# How to convert C# code to Delphi to perform a SHA256 hash and then Base64Url encoding

Tags: c#, delphi, delphi-11-alexandria

I am integrating Xero accounting with my Delphi app. Xero have a VS C# example program, but I've never used C#.

The Xero docs say:
The “code challenge” is created by performing a SHA256 hash on the code verifier and then Base64url encoding the hash

The C# code is:

```
private void btnGenerateLink_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //construct the link that the end user will need to visit in order to authorize the app
    var clientId = txtBoxClientID.Text;
    var scopes = Uri.EscapeUriString(txtBoxScopes.Text);
    var redirectUri = txtBoxRedirectURI.Text;
    var state = txtBoxState.Text;

    //generate the code challenge based on the verifier
    string codeChallenge;
    using (var sha256 = SHA256.Create())
    {
        var challengeBytes = sha256.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(txtBoxCodeVerifier.Text));
        codeChallenge = Convert.ToBase64String(challengeBytes)
            .TrimEnd('=')
            .Replace('+', '-')
            .Replace('/', '_');
    }
    
    var authLink = $"{AuthorisationUrl}?response_type=code&client_id={clientId}&redirect_uri={redirectUri}&scope={scopes}&state={state}&code_challenge={codeChallenge}&code_challenge_method=S256";
    txtBoxAuthLink.Text = authLink;
    btnAuthorise.Enabled = true;
}
```

How do I re-write this in Delphi 11? I have tried the following:

```
var
  inputKey, hash : string;
  b64Encoded : string;
  b64url : TBase64UrlEncoding;
begin
  //create the code challenge
  inputKey := eCodeVerifier.Text;

  hash := THashSHA2.GetHashString(inputKey, SHA256);
  b64url := TBase64UrlEncoding.Create;
  b64Encoded := b64url.Encode(hash);
```

Comment: SO really isn't a code translation service. How do you re-write it in Delphi? You first understand what the code is doing in C#, and then you write Delphi code to do the same. Which part of this can't you do? What have you tried? You don't understand any C#? So do some learning. If you know how to perform sha256 hashes in delphi, and how to encode as base64, then you don't even need to know C# to be able to understand this code.

Comment: Use ChatGBT to translate code to Delphi. Good luck!

Comment: I've edited the original post to show what I've tried.

Comment: You didn't do the utf8 part. You need to do some debugging also. Run the C# and the Delphi code side by side and get your programs to output the intermediate values. Check that they match. When they don't match, you know which bit went wrong. It's very hard to succeed without learning basic debugging skills like this. I sometimes think that modern tools hinder learning of such tools.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not an exact translation of the presented C# code, but hopefully answering your underlying question: here is a function that, given a PKCE code verifier, returns the SHA256 code challenge:

```
uses
  System.SysUtils, System.Hash, System.NetEncoding;

function GetCodeChallenge(const ACodeVerifier: string): string;
var
  LSHA256: string;
  LSHA256Bytes: TBytes;
begin
  LSHA256Bytes := THashSHA2.GetHashBytes(ACodeVerifier, THashSHA2.TSHA2Version.SHA256);
  LSHA256 := TNetEncoding.Base64.EncodeBytesToString(LSHA256Bytes);
  // The following three lines are what makes
  // a "Base64 encoding" into a "Base 64 URL encoding" - no more magic than that
  Result := StringReplace(LSHA256, '=', '', [rfReplaceAll]);
  Result := StringReplace(Result, '+', '-', [rfReplaceAll]);
  Result := StringReplace(Result, '/', '_', [rfReplaceAll]);
end;
```

Also worth mentioning, perhaps, is that a PKCE code verifier must be a random string of length min 43 and max 128.